# Как принять бинарный файл и сохранить на диск?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa.js

С клиента отправляю картинку в base64, как мне ее принять на сервере Koa.js и сохранить.

То что отправляется:

------WebKitFormBoundaryZipFmBdBUSkH3VfP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="k"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG

IHDR¼ôßYþß IDATx^ì½ydÉqå{cÍ½za7I5Q¤Ä)Ð@Ð÷ÿ_ÀèAOzÒH=l²Idw-{ÄàwÌ7næÄB!3#îânî7üØ±cæÓétêÆ×hÑgºÇâóý¬{õêU·.»ý~ÿ¦Óiw{{÷øìp8tÛí¶»¹¹Éï¼Ç5øÉù<»Ùlßýl>wíªÛl6¿óÚívÝÝépÈ9?LrÞîxÈÏ×¯*wï¿ÿ~~ç~ü|||Ì¹suuÕ-góþÞOOÝÕrÙßãÍ7im¾»»ëão^÷÷÷ÝÓÓSîËúÁ=EÚ°Z­r¿»¹í¦I®É½yñùîP6 ´ó}·\Ìû>ñ9ÙG®©ÍÊ>Ûn¹Xä®ëøÂ:M'¹ãÃãlçsMlÊ1Ë{´ûsíõóANß¯¯¯óyÆcw»¼Gÿù9í&¹?}öã]®Å=h?cÏ5èó1aðÞóós÷áæ¼<ºÍfóiÇsì×*]sàÅ´s¹/úÊñ·Yïú¹ãÚvÝl6ííMø<Ô8¾çtÚuÛ]9í£mµ6á~y_ûÑ.þsÏõzÝ­×«n6g8|FÛíö÷\lËã¼màæ×¡¼½ï~Uøû`Éév`'çõf½î¦m>zOGãú^g¶¨1tÜÇé¬Ë8`7»~­×¹×>ÝqL;y>eÌfõ,ÑFcNÝÝÝwÓIã÷÷uþk/ÚÃ1ô÷|&¸>íáºÚïÙ|ÖýøÓO»>ø   OËø-0Z@LFÀ;NÑïXàTÀàçEÇÙFr:ºÅr   @Äc1gcAvQeAf±ÔþXðX¸Æt2ívû]@]¿KÀÍuw:Æ´±_äXæú¼X@óy÷üôð3¸i÷¡]ïÀó>}§E,>¯¿Ýd:`  á¶7Îºë+Àí,: ÿØå<««ï´©ùu·ZÕ~8ÖyÕíMq±+ý|ñð{__]uÇI-^úÜp3é
ø\\Ì»Ã¾ìA;ÎÝ)¶(Þl
´ºÞ77ô¯ìûô¼Ê9:>¢ñé´vÀÞ_¿ü:m¤ðXn¶ë©àvk7Á:mpq

Comment: https://github.com/koajs/examples/blob/master/upload/app.js

Comment: @nörbörnën, Почему то ctx.request.files === undefind

Comment: ну так у тебя `k`, кажется

Comment: @nörbörnën, всё, получилось, я body-parser перепутал с koa-body

Comment: молодец, что разобрался. теперь напиши тут ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS имеет btoa() function для этого.

Например:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa('your-binary-data');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Но я думаю, что ваши двоичные данные в pastebin неверны - данные в формате jpeg должны заканчиваться на «ffd9».

**UPDATE**

Нужно написать простой шестнадцатеричный конвертер в base64:

```
function hexToBase64(str) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
}
```

И использовать это:

```
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + hexToBase64('your-binary-data');
```

Смотрите рабочий пример с вашими шестнадцатеричными данными на  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79NnG/)